# Display array items one at a time in Text Widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using this array to use its value inside Text Widget:

```
var heartData = ['76','76','80', '76','82','75','73','75'];
```

Now i want to display this array data one by one in text Widget:

```
StreamBuilder<List<int>>(
                                    stream: stream,
                                    initialData: lastValue,
                                    builder: (BuildContext context,
                                        AsyncSnapshot<List<int>> snapshot) {
                                      if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                          ConnectionState.active) {
                                        var currentVal =
                                            snapshot.data.toString();
                                        int currentValue = int.parse(
                                            currentVal.substring(
                                                1, currentVal.length - 1),
                                            onError: (source) => -1);
                                        print("String data $currentValue");
                                        if (currentValue == 2) {
                                      
                                          return FutureBuilder(
                                              future: Future.delayed(
                                                  const Duration(seconds: 0),
                                                  () async {
    
                                                Seziurealert();
                                              }),
                                              builder: (context, snapshot) {
             // I want to display array data here one by one
                                                return Text(
                                                  'heartData[i]',
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontFamily:
                                                        'SF Pro Display',
                                                    fontSize: 19,
                                                    color:
                                                        const Color(0xffffffff),
                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                                    height: 1.4736842105263157,
                                                  ),
                                                );
                                              });
                                        } else if (currentValue == 0) {
                                          return Text(
                                            'Device not calibrated',
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              fontFamily: 'SF Pro Display',
                                              fontSize: 19,
                                              color: const Color(0xffffffff),
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                              height: 1.4736842105263157,
                                            ),
                                          );
                                        } else if (currentValue == 1) {
    // I want to display array data here one by one
                                          return Text(
                                            'heartData[i]',
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              fontFamily: 'SF Pro Display',
                                              fontSize: 19,
                                              color: const Color(0xffffffff),
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                              height: 1.4736842105263157,
                                            ),
                                          );
                                        }
    // I want to display array data here one by one
                                        return Text(
                                          'heartData[i]',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            fontFamily: 'SF Pro Display',
                                            fontSize: 19,
                                            color: const Color(0xffffffff),
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                            height: 1.4736842105263157,
                                          ),
                                        );
                                      } else {
                                        return Text(
                                          'Check the stream',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            fontFamily: 'SF Pro Display',
                                            fontSize: 19,
                                            color: const Color(0xffffffff),
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                            height: 1.4736842105263157,
                                          ),
                                        );
                                      }
                                    },
                                  ),
```

Please help me out how can I use this array inside my Text widget? I am using this Text inside Stream Builder and Text widget is displayed when a condition is met
I want to fetch this data one by one and not in List form. How can I achieve that?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

there is a method called `join` in array, you can call it:

```
 return Text(
  heartData.join(),
  style: TextStyle (
    fontFamily: 'SF Pro Display',
    fontSize: 19,
    color: const Color(0xffffffff),
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
    height: 1.4736842105263157,
  ),
);
```

result will be 7676807682757375

You can also pass separator to this function `heartData.join(separator: "-")`

result will be 76-76-80-76-82-75-73-75

Comment: But I don't want the whole array to come at the same time, I want it that the first 76 should be displayed as Text then it goes and the next number in the array i.e again 76 should be displayed, and so on until the array is finished.